# Prove that a function has a continuous representative

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose that $[f]\in L_\infty(\mathbb{R})$, here $[]$ is used to signify that this is a equivalence class. Let $T_a[f](x) = f(x+a)$. How can one show that if $\|T_a[f]-[f]\|_\infty\rightarrow 0$ as $a\rightarrow 0$ then $[f]$ has a continuous representative?

Comment: I'm guessing you'll have to build one based on the definition. Define a representative so that the infinity norm is the supremum norm, and then use the definition of continuity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints: Let $f_n(x)=\frac 1 n \int_x^{x+\frac1 n} f(t)dt$. Then

$f_n$ is continuous for each $n$

$f_n$ is  uniformly bounded.

On $[-N,N]$, $(f_n)$ is equi-continuous and hence has a subsequence which converges uniformly to a continuous function (by Arzela-Ascoli Theorem ) for each positive integer $N$.

By Lebesgue's Theorem $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ a.e..

It follows that $f$ is a.e. equal to a  continuous function on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Very nice solution ! Thanks